# How set a timezone in Chart js or avoid a DST issue

Tags: chart.js, moment-timezone

I have a chart js (2.9.4) based on measurements from around the globe.

The API I call renders the dates in the local time of the measurement.

That works fine but chart js has an issue with hours that don't exist, meaning when we skip one hour end of March from wintertime to summertime. In Brussels/Europe this is 2:00 AM.

The xAxes code:

```js
xAxes: [{
   stacked: true,
   type: 'time',
   distribution: 'series',
   time: {
      unit: 'day'
   },
   ticks:  {
      fontSize: 10
   }
}],
```

How can I pass the timezone to chart js? I haven't found a solution that works yet.

An image from a measurement in Ireland and the hour that cause the bug. In my local time that hour does not exist. In Ireland it does.
[image]

Comment: do you have the timezone information? or does your server simply returns what you show in the last image? ("YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm")?

Comment: @Moshezauros I know the timezone, but no idea how to tell chart.js

Comment: how about using a library like `moment.js` to convert the timezone?